# Crop Out a Triangle from Image

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap, crop

I am trying to crop an Image using AS3.

I have no problem in cropping a rectangle from a Bitmap.

A problem arises, since I need a triangle Image (a rectangle with 2 of it sides transparent).

Please take a look at the following image

http://s8.postimg.org/6dd24pix1/Untitled_3_copy.png

I know this isnt exactly *cropping*, but rather making the pixels on the sides disappear, but I am having problem achieving that.

Any help on this please?

Thank you.

Jay van Diyk

Comment: And you want that to be an image? You can not just use a mask to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a mask, this makes everything outside that triangle transparent too.
Like so:

```
// Creating triangle
var triangle:Sprite = new Sprite();
triangle.graphics.beginFill(0, 1);
triangle.graphics.moveTo(image.width / 2, 0);
triangle.graphics.lineTo(image.width, image.height);
triangle.graphics.lineTo(0, image.height);
triangle.graphics.lineTo(image.width / 2, 0);
triangle.graphics.endFill();

image.mask = triangle;
addChild(image);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, but I need to save the "triangle" image as a file. Would this masking method work?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, but I need to save the "triangle" image as a PNG file (the "white part" being transparent). Would this masking method work if I were to do that?